# Generating lambda expression - Type conversion Error

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, generic-programming

I have a generic method that filters a list of entities, filtering is done by generating lambda expressions:

```
protected object initFilters<TEntity>(string targetEntity, List<SearchItem> searchItems, int page_size = 20, int offset = 0 , ExpressionSortCriteria<TEntity, string> SortCriteria)
{
   var SearchQuery = new SearchQuery<TEntity>();

   if (searchItems != null)
   {
      var predicat = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<TEntity>(searchItems).Compile();
      SearchQuery.AddFilter(predicat);
   }
   //SearchQuery.AddSortCriteria(new ExpressionSortCriteria<Profile, string> { SortExpression = (profile => profile.Libelle), Direction = SortDirection.Ascending });
   SearchQuery.Skip = offset;
   SearchQuery.Take = page_size;

   return (object)SearchQuery;
}
```

My `SearchQuery` contains criteria that will be applied to the list.

My predicate is build by a method in this way :

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<SearchItem> filters)
{
             some code ...

             return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
}
```

My `AddFilter` (in the `searchQuery`) is like this :

```
public void AddFilter(Expression<Func<TEntity, Boolean>> filter)
{
    Filters.Add(filter);
}
```

I have a problem with this line :

```
SearchQuery.AddFilter(predicat);
```

Error:

> cannot convert from System.Func to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>

As you see , my two methods are using

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

Any idea please how to solve this ?

Comment: No, 
I made it like this : 

                    var SearchQuery = new SearchQuery<TEntity>();
                    if (searchItems != null)
                    {
                        var predicat = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<TEntity>(searchItems).Compile();
                        SearchQuery.AddFilter(predicat);
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your comment, you say you make

```
var SearchQuery = new SearchQuery<TEntity>(); 
if (searchItems != null) { 
  var predicat = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<TEntity>(searchItems).Compile();          
  SearchQuery.AddFilter(predicat); 
}
```

of course, if your compile your Expression, it's no more an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but a `Func<T, bool>`

and AddFilter takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as argument.

So... remove the `Compile()`